# Reaction of mixed carbonyl compound with ethylene glycol in acidic medium

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

> [image: 4‐oxopentanal → ethylene glycol]

I Know that there is cyclic ketal or cyclic acetal is formed when carbonyl compound reacts with ethylene glycol. But I am confused here because I am unable to decide what will be the major product  formed here because there are two possibilities, i.e. cyclic ketal and cyclic acetal.

Can anyone help me in reasoning what will be the major product and why? Also, I want to know the role of dry $\ce{H+}$ in this reaction.

I think the cyclic ketal should be formed as major product because the oxygen of ketone will be more willing to donate lone pair to $\ce{H+}$ and react. Is it correct?

Comment: I presume you are implying a 1/1 molar ratio of ketoaldehyde and ethylene glycol. Are you asking which carbonyl reacts faster (kinetic) or which aetal/ketal is more stable (thermodynamic)?

Comment: Yes,ketoaldehyde and Ethylene glycol are in 1:1 Molar ratio.I want to know which among acetal or ketal will be formed as major product in _this_ reaction,so Kinetic based i.e which carbonyl will react faster and form stable product.

Comment: @Ashutosh aldehydes are more susceptible to nucleophilic substitution so if I’m not wrong, the aldehyde will form the acetal here.

Comment: You are Right ,but isn't this reaction Electrophilic addition (due to H+) I don't see why it would follow Nucleophilic Substitution or Nucleophilic Addition path .

Comment: Complicated by the possibility of intramolecular cyclisation

Comment: The bis-ketal is selectively cleaved with dry FeCl3-silica liberating the ketone and leaving the acetal intact. https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-1987-27833.

Comment: Frankly,I am unable to comfortably understand what do you mean . Can you (or anyone) explain in a simpler language? (I am a high school student)

Comment: Why is no one answering :(